# How do I view the Intent that caused my Android app to resume

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Backdrop, I'm using firebase to do notification.  I'm passing extra info in my notification for my App to bring up a specific page.  That's done through adding extra data in my data field in the Json.  (This part is working).

What I found is that by default a notification click cause the app to load from scratch.  After it loads, the current Intent has the data which started the app so I can call

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

and get my extra data from this bundle.  This was working, but I noticed it restarted the app which seemed like a waste, so I changed the application to not restart every time.  In my AndroidManifest.xml I added:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Which lets it reuse the app.  However, when it does this, it not starts at onStart() rather than onCreate() which I expected, but what I found is that the getIntent() does not have data from the notification I clicked on, from the documentation it sounds like it has the intent from creating the app.

So the question is how can I get the Intent that caused my app to "start' (not create).  I think one possibility might be a listening to the BroadcastManager but don't know if I should be doing that when I'm not currently active.

Comment: did you try overriding **onNewIntent()**?

Comment: Looks like that could work.  Basically I catch the new Intent coming in, save off the data, and then use that when it calls onStart() or onResume() to jump to the screen I want showing.  Sound about right?